# CollectionView or ListView with buttons in each row for my shopping cart

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I know how to add a collectionview and populate it with data from my database. I also know how to select a row in the collectionview and delete that row from a button not in my collectionview (like a button on the bottom of the page)
However what I want to do is to create a remove/delete button in each cell and when that corresponding button is clicked I need to get the collectionview's selected index and remove it.

The problem and help I need is how to code the buttonclick event for each button in thet respected row.

Please help.

HERE IS MY CODE:

***Customer.cs***
namespace TEST
{
public class Customers
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
}

```
***MainPage.cs***
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Customers>CustomerCollection;

        private int _itemId = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CreateCustomerItems();
        }


        private void CreateCustomerItems()
        {

            CustomerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Customers>()
            {
                new Customers(){Id = 134, Name = "John Roberts"},
                new Customers(){Id = 145, Name = "Olyvia Johnson"},
                new Customers(){Id = 154, Name = "Paul Cippone"},
                new Customers(){Id = 163, Name = "Robert Jones"},
                new Customers(){Id = 171, Name = "Shannon Richards"},
                new Customers(){Id = 186, Name = "Tamica Alvirez"},
                new Customers(){Id = 195, Name = "Frank Bellford"},
                new Customers(){Id = 204, Name = "Kathryn Brown"},
            };

            CvTest.ItemsSource = CustomerCollection;
        
        }



        public void Delete(Object Sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            //THIS IS WHERE I AM LOST I CAN GET THE DATA BELOW WITH COLLECTION VIEW SELECTION CHANGED BUT HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THAT HERE? 
            var btn = (Button)Sender;
            //var item = (MainPage)btn.BindingContext;
            //item.

            CustomerCollection.Remove //THIS IS WHERE I AM LOST
        }

       

        private async void CvTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var currentSelection = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Customers;
            if (currentSelection == null) return;

            _itemId = currentSelection.Id;
            await DisplayAlert("Testing", "You selected the CollectionView with the customer id of: " + _itemId.ToString(), "Continue");


        }

    }
}


***MainPage.xaml***
 <CollectionView x:Name="CvTest" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CvTest_SelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  >

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                    <Button Text="Delete" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Clicked="Delete"/>


                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your click handler you can use the `Button`'s `BindingContext`

```
void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    // you will need to cast to the appropriate type of object here
    var item = (YourClassNameHere)btn.BindingContext;

    // you can now lookup item by ID or reference in your Collection
    // and delete/modify/etc it
}
```

for your specific example

```
public void Delete(Object Sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var btn = (Button)Sender;
        var item = (Customer)btn.BindingContext;

        CustomerCollection.Remove(item);
    }
```

Comment: This gives me an error: System.InvalidCastException
Message=Specified cast is not valid. What do you mean by // you will need to cast to the appropriate type of object here

Comment: if your `ItemsSource` is a `List<Widget>`, then you would cast to `Widget` because each row of the list represents one instance of `Widget`

Comment: How would I retrieve the binded data of the same row the clicked button in the same collection view row in the button click event?

Comment: use the code I provided.  That's exactly what it does.  It gets the bound item for the row the button is in.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the **formatted** code there.  Code crammed in comments is impossible to read.

Comment: why are you casting to `MainPage`?  As I explained, your `ItemsSource` is a `List<Customer>` so each row is a `Customer`.  That's the class you should cast to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. You helped me to finally figure this out.